# Airflow scheduler stops without errors or warning

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm running Airflow 1.10.2 for the last 3 years now, without any problems.
Suddenly since 1 month, jobs stop being scheduled. Looking at the airflow-scheduler.out, it shows `{jobs.py:1559} INFO - Harvesting DAG parsing result` for as long as the eye can see.
Quitting the scheduler with  `kill -9 ps aux | grep 'airflow scheduler' | awk '{print $2}'` , removing all scheduler files with `rm -rf airflow-scheduler.err airflow-scheduler.log airflow-scheduler.out airflow-scheduler.pid` and starting the scheduler again `airflow scheduler -D` schedules the jobs again correctly. But after a few hours the same happens.

I've checked disk usage and memory usage, all fine (80 gb of free space). Also the CPU keeps running at normal levels.

It is driving me nuts, especially since nothing has changed.
What is going on?

Many thanks,

Comment: to confirm if you tail the airflow-scheduler.err and .log there is nothing indicative of the error

Comment: No, they are both empty. There is only INFO logged in the .out file